# Mount/umount remote share before/after running a systemd service

Tags: systemd

I'd like to use *systemd* to run a script that does a backup by saving the data to remote storage, so:

- mount remote storage (e.g. NFS share)
- run the script
- umount remote storage

This is what I tried to do:

`cat /etc/systemd/system/mnt-server-share.mount`

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote storage test
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=server:/share
Where=/mnt/server/share
Type=nfs
Options=defaults,noauto
TimeoutSec=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`cat /etc/systemd/system/backuptest.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote backup test
RequiresMountsFor=/mnt/server/share

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup.sh
ExecStop= systemctl stop mnt-server-share.mount

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But after script end/fail the remote stogare is not `umount`. I could put `mount`/`umount` in the script, but I wish I could do it with *systemd* ... Can anyone help me do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your automount file `/etc/systemd/system/mnt-server-share.mount` specify an idle timeout value.

```
TimeoutIdleSec=

      Configures an idle timeout. Once the mount has been idle for the specified time, systemd will attempt to unmount. Takes a unit-less value in seconds, or a time span value such as "5min 20s". Pass 0 to disable the timeout logic. The timeout is disabled by default.
```

From your example:

```
[Unit]
Description=Remote storage test
After=network.target

[Mount]
What=server:/share
Where=/mnt/server/share
Type=nfs
Options=defaults,noauto
TimeoutSec=30
TimeoutIdleSec=1m

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! I thought I could eliminate `ExecStop` instead, doing some tests, it seems to be necessary: why?